# Has anyone gotten ServiceStack.Text to compile on WinPhone 8/8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, servicestack-text

I have a cross-platform project that is using ServiceStack.text.  THe PCL does not support Windows Phone 8/8.1.  I thought I could try to compile it from source but it seems that the WP8 project in Github does not compile.

Has anyone gotten this to work?  Any tips to share?